# Correct way to represent a one-to-one relationship (reference) in UML

Tags: database-design, uml

I have two tables with a one-to-one relationship between them:

```
Person
 - Id
 - HouseFk

House
 - Id
```

Person has a foreign key to House. Note that HouseFk can also be NULL. What would be a correct way to represent this in UML ? I can come up with two variations in notation:

1-to-0..1:

```
      1     0..1    
Person----------House
```

0..1-to-1:

```
      0..1     1    
Person----------House
```

Which way around is it and why ? I'm really confused because I've heared that one-to-many relationship has the placement of the key reversed, meaning that B refers to A, from which one can deduce that in one-to-one (although in my case, it's one-to-zero-or-one) scenario, A refers to B, and therefore 0..1 is on B side (first)? Or A side (second) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are the rules of your relationship?  You need to define that first. Person 'owns' house? Person 'lives in' House?  Let's assume it's 'owns' for the moment.  You then have several options:

**Option 1: no optionality (mandatory 1:1):**

```
- Each Person must own exactly one House
- Each House must be owned by exactly one Person
```

This would be represented

```
       1           1
Person ------------- House
```

**Option 2a: optional one way:**

```
 - Each Person may own at most one House
 - A Person need not own any Houses
 - Each House must be owned by exactly one Person
```

This would be represented

```
       1        0..1
Person ------------- House
```

**Option 2b: optional the other way:**

```
 - Each Person must own exactly one House
 - Each House may be owned by at most one Person
 - A House need not be owned by any Person
```

This would be represented

```
       0..1        1
Person ------------- House
```

**Option 3: optional both ways:**

```
 - Each Person may own at most one House
 - A Person need not own any Houses
 - Each House may be owned by at most one Person
 - A House need not be owned by any Person
```

This would be represented

```
       0..1     0..1
Person ------------- House
```

**EDIT(*)**

Your DB schema as it stands is none of the above.  It says:

```
 - Each Person may own at most one House
 - A Person need not own any Houses
 - Each House may be owned by many People
 - A House need not be owned by any Person
```

Not sure if that's what you want....? [Shout if you don't understand why].

hth.

*Thanks to ypercube for pointing out correction in comments below.

Comment: It's option-3 only if `HouseFK` has `UNIQUE` constraint. Otherwise it's option-4: `0..n::0..1`